# JQuery Append actionlink to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
//code
 $(document).on("click", ".open-chartModal", function () {
    var spNames = $(this).data('id');
    $("#spNames").val(spNames);

    var separated = spNames.split(";");

    for (var i = 0, length = separated.length; i < length; i++) {
            var chunk = separated[i];

            $('#options').append('<li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Chart", "Chart", 
            new { spName = "'+ chunk +'"   }, new AjaxOptions { }) </li>')

     }
   });
```

The above is reading 'chunk' as string and not a variable. I want to put spNames = var chunk. Do not know if the single quotes are in correct place.

Comment: js/jquery works on client side and it seems that you have used some serverside code too, so to me error is there (_seems to me_).

Comment: What do you mean string instead of variable? Javascript will always automatically cast values to a string when concatenating with other strings.  Do you need it as a number?

Comment: Jai I have added the above code to be more clear.

Comment: Bic I want the value of variable chunk to be inserted in the append and currently its NOT - its adding "spName=chunk"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var url = '@Ajax.ActionLink("Chart", "Chart",  new { spName = "-1"   }, new AjaxOptions { })';
$('#options').append('<li>' + url.replace('-1', chunk )+ '</li>')
```

As `@Ajax.ActionLink` will be rendered by razor. You can't pass JavaScript variables.

You can add an placeholder value & replace it with your variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
for (var i = 0, length = separated.length; i < length; i++) {
            var chunk = separated[i];

            $('#options').append('<li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Chart", "Chart",' +
            'new { spName = "'+ chunk +'"   }, new AjaxOptions { }) </li>')

}
```

Your newline broke your string literal. Need to close it and explicitly concatenate.

Comment: I put your code from above in a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/HmLPz/ - it seems to be doing what you want. Take a look at tell me if it's different than the behavior you're seeing?